# MPMusicPlayerController does not playing Music on tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

Hey there im trying to play music by MPMusicPlayerController.
But when i start to prepare the player it goes into a timeout. (not in the completionHandler)
Here is the Error:
*[SDKPlayback] applicationQueuePlayer _establishConnectionIfNeeded timeout [ping did not pong]*

```
        self.musicPlayer.setQueue(with: ["1033200131"])
        self.musicPlayer.prepareToPlay { err in
            if let error = err {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            self.musicPlayer.play()
        }
```

tvOS-Version: 14.6 Beta

Hope anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Did you try using the `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer`? The systemMusicPlayer works for me, but using the applicationMusicPlayer it gives me the same timeout.